# gradle sync error in android 2.2.3

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing a horrified error. After installing android studio 2.2.3, i couldn't build my very first project due to gradle error. I even tried using maven link but i use my PC offline. The following is my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.samim.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am also posting an image regarding the errors.

[image: Error messages]

[After doing clean build and rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBmP6.jpg)

[project gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bRMy.png)

Comment: Have you checked `offline work` in setting?? Its in `Setting>>Build, Execution, Deplooyment>>Gradle` if so uncheck it, connect to internet and sync gradle with project files

Comment: no i haven't checked offline. i am online since my installation. actually this is my clean second installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to add **untrusted server certificates** automatically to android studio when using the internet from workplace. Go to Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates, now check "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically". After this coding can be done offline.

Also using a third party VPN solves certificate issues.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using maven link but i use my PC offline

That's your problem.

Gradle uses the exact same sources as Maven would.

---

Once you get online, your dependencies should resolve from any "New Project" in Android Studio. You then should let the dependencies download, and then you are welcome to work offline.

Note: You also need to download the Android SDK

Comment: i have seen my friends coding offline. my internet was live when i first installed android studio.

Comment: You can code offline only **after** Gradle has cached the dependencies

Comment: my laptop is online now. i tried creating a new project but the problem is still there.

Comment: Try to clean the project and run the app. It should download outstanding libraries

Comment: Then you are missing a `repositories { jcenter() }` in a `build.gradle` file that you've not shown in the question

Comment: ok now i have added the project gradle screen shot to my question.

Comment: oh yes firewall might be an issue. my company internet is using a customized certificate for google, youtube etc.

Comment: although i added that certificate to trusted certificates

Comment: thnx for d answers. i guess i have to install it using my mobile internet.

Comment: thank u guys for your precious time. i finally fixed it using my mobile internet as the files were not getting downloaded due to my company's firewall.